# Which directories are mapped to which domain names?

Tags: linux, centos, domain-name, mapping

In my `/home` directory there are a bunch of directories that each represent a website. Some of these directory names are the same name as the domain name so those are obvious. But other directory names are a bit obscure and there's no easy way for me to tell which domain they are for. How can I easily see which domain names all these directories are mapped to?

Comment: Look at your web server configuration.

Comment: Apache? Which file?

Comment: Dunno why not start simple and just grep the file(s) for a domain name that you know works.

Comment: Who configured the web server?

Comment: Someone else configured it - the previous developer probably. Will try grep.